# find all spinners that match a tag

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Is it possible to get a list or find all `Spinner` that match a specific tag?

I would like the user to be able to add new `Spinner` widgets on the fly, but I need to be able to dynamically get the values from each `Spinner`.

In `jQuery`, I can select all elements that match a class by `$('.myClassSelector').each()`. Can this, or something similar, be done in Android?

**UPDATE**
All spinners are in a specific `LinearLayout` that is specified in XML. The layout is used as a container for all of the spinners.

Comment: walk the main layout tree looking for spinners.

Comment: can you give a bit more idea of your requirement? like can we add all spinner in same linear layout which is already exists in xml or we need to add them in different-different layout as per requirement.

Comment: Updated the post; they are all added to a `LinearLayout` specified in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get all the child of the layout in which you previously added the `Spinner` and check if the child is `Spinner` or not.

```
    LinearLayout ll = //Your Layout this can be any Linear or Relative layout 
                     //in which you added your spinners at runtime ;

    int count = ll.getChildCount();
    for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
    {
        View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof Spinner)
        {
            // you got the spinner
            Spinner s = (Spinner) v;
            Log.i("Item selected",s.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if possible it would be better to add all spinners in same linear layout and as use FasteKerinns solution but iff not possible try some thing like below.....

```
Vector spinners = new Vector ():

private void treverseGroup(ViewGroup vg)
{
    final int count = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof Spinner) 
        {

          spinners.add(vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
        else if (vg.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup)
            recurseGroup((ViewGroup) gp.getChildAt(i));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method below has the ability to retrieve all Spinners in the **entire view hierarchy** rooted at `root` **without using recursion**. It also matches a given tag.

```
private ArrayList<Spinner> getSpinners(ViewGroup root, Object matchingTag) {
    ArrayList<?> list = root.getTouchables();

    Iterator<?> it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        View view = (View) it.next();
        if (!(view instanceof Spinner && view.getTag().equals(matchingTag))) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    return (ArrayList<Spinner>) list;
}
```

Comment: It's funny, I had just coded this method in my project to get all `EditText`s.

Comment: You might want to check the return value of `getTag()` for null before calling `equals()`.

Comment: Why is it not possible do the same thing for textview.Is textt view not a touchable then what is it called?